# AppWidget animation in android

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget

I created a WiFi widget which provide the user a easy access to WiFi. 
The widget functionalities are working fine. 
Now I want to show an animation to the widget. While connecting the signal bar periodically light once and go upward until the WiFi is enabled. 
For that I created an Image-array with different signal levels.

While Connection i am calling a Method startAnimation.

```
public void StartAnimation()
{
    System.out.println("start");
    frame = 0;
    animationFlag = true;
    if(!handler.hasMessages(0))
    handler.postDelayed(AnimateRunnable, FRAME_RATE);



}
```

From the satrtAnimation I am making animationFlag to true.

After that the state becomes Enbaled or Not connected That time i am calling stopAnimation method.

```
public void StopAnimation()
{
    System.out.println("Stop Animation Before:"+animationFlag);
    animationFlag = false;
    System.out.println("Stop Animation:After:"+animationFlag);
    if(!handler.hasMessages(0)) {
        System.out.println("handler.hasmessage0");
        handler.removeCallbacks(AnimateRunnable);
    }


}
```

Here I am making the animationFlag false. and printing its values before and after. It displays correctly.

But in My Runnable animation flag remains true. So my widget getting hanged

```
final Runnable AnimateRunnable =new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("run:"+animationFlag);
        if(animationFlag)
        {
            System.out.println("Animation Flag:"+animationFlag);
            AppWidgetManager ap =AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mContext);
            frame = ++frame%5;
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.wifi_signal_strength,rangeImages[frame]);
            ap.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

                handler.postDelayed(AnimateRunnable, FRAME_RATE);



        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that app widget layout is defined in your application, it is not your view and you can not manipulate it directly.  Neither are all views allowed to be in app widget layout. This view is managed by launcher,  and layout passed to it via obscure methods ( which we can not discuss here)

When you like to change your app widget contents, you have to do it via manager and remote views object:

```
   private static void updateWidgetState(Context context, CharSequence amountCameras, String locationCity, String locationStatus) {
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.camera_widget_layout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.camerawidget, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, CameraWatch.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_amount_cameras, amountCameras);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_location, locationCity);
    // views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_security, securityStatus);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.locationStatus, locationStatus);

    final int[] appWidgetIds = manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(CameraWidgetProvider.class.getPackage().getName(), CameraWidgetProvider.class.getName()));

    manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "widget state changed");
}
```

See docs on RemoteViews -  that's about all functionality you can get. No animation